# Responsive Width and Height Layout using css or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, responsive-design

I am trying to create one page responsive html layout.

Here is my dummy image 
[image: images]

First layout is what i am trying to achieve but if it's really hard then the 2nd layout is also OK for me.

I am trying to make the home landing area or slide fit completely on screen (**fullscreen**)

i found a [wordpress template](http://bookofpixels.com/immersion/) which is similar to layout2 but i cant figure our how they had did that.

Comment: I recommend you try putting something together then come back and ask for help if you need it - there are plenty of responsive layout templates/frameworks out there. Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask for a "complete solution" starting with nothing.

Comment: but the daniel solved my problem here itself, am asking only the responsive part of a slide not complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to make sure your content fits in 100% height and width. Also your body and HTML tag needs 100% height and width.

CSS:

```
body,html,.content,.contact,header{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.content{
  background:yellow;
}
header{
  background:red;
}
.contact{
  background:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>

</header>
<div class='content'>

</div>
<div class='contact'>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me. newbie here :)

Answer (score 0):

try to see this and try to update 
http://jsfiddle.net/H2RyR/

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>

html, body, #header,#content,#footer{width:100%;height:100%;}
#header{ background-color:blue;}
#content{ background:red;}
#footer{ background:green;}
```

Comment: yes actually i forget to add 100% for HTML. 

and margin 0 and padding 0 also needed.